# prevent the post back vb and javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

this is a post back problem (I don't want to use the client side to solve this issue , there must be a way to prevent the postBack then using the client side ) , i have a button when clicked it calls a javascript function from the code behind , but before it does this it post back the page , Question is : how can i skip the post back step and jump to the javascript part ??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hello(name) {
        alert("hello world from javascript " + name)
        return false;
    }
</script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
</form>
```

code Behind :

```
    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Myname As String = "myName"
    Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "MyKey", "hello('" & Myname & "');", True)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a client side handler instead of a server side handler. Remove `Button1_Click` and add your js call as an `OnClientClick` attribute value.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" 
            OnClientClick="return hello('myName');" />
```

Or, don't use a server control at all:

```
<button id="button1" onclick="return hello('myName');">Button</button>
```

Comment: You need to `return hello('myName')` in order to disable page postback.

Comment: Yes you do, thanks. It's been awhile since I've written obtrusive javascript.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should register this script in page_load or method before the button click event.

   Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick","return hello()");
2. Use return before the call of hello method where you register script in code behind like this

   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, "MyKey", "return hello('" & Myname & "');", True)
3. Remove all statement from Button1_Click if you do not want postback. Or unbind server side click event

   Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub

Comment: You were register the call for hello method on wrong place. Add this code in page load as I mentioned in my answer it should work

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a HTML button rather than an ASP button

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" runat="server" />
```

And server side write something like

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick","hello()");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking to use the `OnClientClick` event of the button:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClientClick="return hello('world')" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```